# Python - flask and werkzeug - Keep giving "BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'file'"

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-400, werkzeug

I'm trying for the first time to upload file with python, I tried using flask and werkzeug libraries, here is my code:

Here I'm creating the function to upload files:

```
@app.route('/upload')
def upload_file():
    return render_template('load.html')

@app.route('/uploader', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required(must=[be_admin, have_approval])
def uploaderV():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       file = request.files['file']
       if file:
          filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
          file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))
          return 'file uploaded'
    return render_template('load.html')
```

Than this is my load.html page:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Secret{% endblock %}
{% block page_body %}
     <div class="row">
          <form action="{{ url_for('uploaderV') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <p>
                   <input type='file' name='file[]' multiple=''>
                   <input type="submit" value="Upload">
               </p>
          </form>
     </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Every time I try to upload a file the server gives me 
**werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError
BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'file'** 
I tried in different ways, and now I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Change the line `file = request.files['file']` to `file = request.files.get('file')`

Answer (score 2):

Your input name is `file[]` , not `file`. Try something like:

```
   file = request.files['file[]']
```

Or just change your input name to `file`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I haven't the 400 error, it doesn't save any file in my directory but the error is vanished

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be, it works for me in a very simple example.

Comment: Maybe i set in the wrong way the UPLOAD_FOLDER

    UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/tmp'
    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

Comment: Solved mate, thanks a lot, for the file saving I was trying to save on a removable device, in local folder saves